# PHP - How do I modify variables within an array?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

So with this code:

```
$x = 'hello  world';
$y = 'bye world';
$arr = array ($x, $y);

$arr[0] = 'new string';
var_dump($x);
```

`$arr[0] = 'new string';` it's not changing the value of `$x`. How can I change `$x` value referencing the array position?

Comment: print_r($arr) you are going to replace array[0] index value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a reference to `$x`, instead of copying the variable. When passing it into the array as you are, you are merely copying the value of `$x`, and inserting that copy into the array. If you instead pass `$x` as a reference, using `&$x`, any updates made will be made to `$x` instead. Since the value is a reference, it will be updated "both places".

```php
$x = 'hello  world';
$y = 'bye world';
$arr = array (&$x, $y);

$arr[0] = 'new string';
var_dump($x);
```

Output:

> string(10) "new string"

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/KSeKg

Answer (score 1):

The value of `$x` will be copied to the array! There is no reference from `$arr[0]` to `$x`!